# all capabilities in dropdown list

Tags: php, wordpress, for-loop, capability

I'm trying to put all possible capabilities into a dropdown list. I'm new to this so go easy on me. What I have at the moment is not working in the slightest bit:

```
$user = get_user_by('id', '1');
$capslist = $user->allcaps; 
$dropdown = '<select>';
foreach($capslist as $cap){
$dropdown .= '<option value="'.$cap.'">'.$cap.'</option>';
}
$dropdown .= '</select>';
return $dropdown;
```

EDIT --

I made it a shortcode just for a quick test:

```
add_shortcode('capsdropdown', 'sc_capsdropdown');
function sc_capsdropdown($attr) {
$user = get_user_by('id', '1');
$capslist = $user->allcaps; 
$dropdown = '<select>';
foreach($capslist as $cap){
$dropdown .= '<option value="'.$cap.'">'.$cap.'</option>';
}
$dropdown .= '</select>';
return $dropdown;
}
```

and it DOES create a dropdown. Problem is, it's boolean. It's all 1s. Any way to get it to return the actual cap names?

-- EDIT: It's weird because vardump($user->allcaps); returns the actual values, not boolean. I tried using settype but it didn't affect the output.

Comment: Your code seems good to me. Where have you implemented it?

Comment: So far just in the page editor with exec php activated. other php statements are working but when i throw this in there, the whole page loop goes blank. just getting page title and header/footer.

Comment: see updated post. progress. not quite there yet.

Comment: This is a shot in the dark, but try this: `foreach($capslist as $k=>$cap){
$dropdown .= '<option value="'.$k.'">'.$k.'</option>';
}`

Comment: A crack shot in the dark! Totally worked. Thank you! Write that up as an answer and I'll mark it answered. (Then maybe explain to me _how_ that worked! ;)

Comment: Cool! Glad it all worked out for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
foreach($capslist as $k=>$cap){
    $dropdown .= '<option value="'.$k.'">'.$k.'</option>';
}
```

My guess was how the array was structured. Each Array Key was the actual name of the capability, with its value being a simple boolean determining whether or not the given user instance had the permission to perform that given action.

You were searching for the capabilities by name, and since you were only seeing 1s in the output, I figured what you were looking for was in the keys.

Comment: Thanks for that explanation. Right on the money.